# Replace delimited string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
Mr Blue has a //start blue house and a blue //end car.
```

And I want to replace the delimited string with //start and //end so the string became:

```
Mr Blue has a car.
```

I've tried

```
var res = str.replace(\//start(.*?)\//end, "");
```

It didn't work.

Comment: I don't think that's even valid in Javascript. Try `/\/\/start(.*?)\/\/end/`

Comment: @LABLEBI: What about the spaces around? Do you need to keep just 1? Will there be `//starting` or `//ending` words anywhere?

Comment: the problem is that dot in `/\/\/start(.*?)\/\/end/` matches any character except new line and I want to match any thing between delimiter including new lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this regex to match any charachter in between delimiter including line break `\/\/start((.|\n)*)\/\/end`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a this regex:

```
\/\/start(.*?)\/\/end
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV0dU3/2)**

Javascript code

```
var re = /\/\/start(.*?)\/\/end/; 
var str = ' //start blue house and a blue //end';

var result = str.replace(re, '$1');
```

Comment: great, but when i do a line break in string the reg doesn't work any more

Comment: @LABLEBI you can use the single line flag as this: `(?s)\/\/start(.*?)\/\/end` or you could use `\/\/start([\s\S]*?)\/\/end`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var string = "Mr Blue has a //start blue house and a blue //end car. "
string = string.replace(/\/\/.*?\/\/\w+\s+/g, "");
alert(string)
```

---

## Output:

```
Mr Blue has a car.
```

---

## Demo:

http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/EjjPNe

---

## Regex Explanation:

```
//.*?//\w+\s+


Match the character string “//” literally «//»
Match any single character that is NOT a line break character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character string “//” literally «//»
Match a single character that is a “word character” «\w+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” «\s+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
```